# Simple PHP url Help needed

Tags: php, variables

I am new to php, I need small help

I m creating a page in php named index.php

i want when someone view that page automatically a number or anything would be added to the url end

```
Like www.abc.com/index.php ---> www.abc.com/index.php?abc or ?132
```

when ever that index page is refreshed it should get a number or any variable in the end

Comment: a random number? or what number is it uniq? try www.abc.com/index.php?id=yourvariable

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_GET["123"])) {
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ."?123");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$QS = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$URL = "http://www.example.com/index.php";

// Check if Anything already assigned
if( empty($QS) ) {
   // Generate Any RANDOM Number Here
   $NUM = mt_rand(999, 9999);

   // Reload Page and assign number
   header("Location: {$URL}?{$NUM}");
}
```

Place this code in the very top of your page

Comment: concatenate `$NUM` with `$URL`

Comment: This worked but when i reloaded the page it shows the same id generated.,,, I want when some one reloads the page or try to attempt the same id new id should be allotted to generated

Comment: @AkutiSharma, If you want random key every time then just comment the `if( empty($QS) ) {` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
<?php

    $num = '123';

    if(!isset($_GET[$num])){
          header("Location: /path/to/page?$num");
    }
```